# Python: string append in list with unicode issue

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, pyspark

I scraped from a website which is written by Mandarin. (I ran this code by using Pyspark)

```
lis=[]
ctype=soup.select_one('.car-type')
car_type=ctype.text
car_type=car_type.replace('\n', '').replace('\t','')
car_type1=car_type.split('[')[1].split(',')[0]
print(car_type1)
print(type(car_type1))
lis.append(car_type1)
print(lis)
```

Following is the output:

```
Z(76.9萬)

type 'unicode'

[u'Z(76.9\u842c)']
```

So I converted from unicode to string.

```
lis=[]
ctype=soup.select_one('.car-type')
car_type=ctype.text
car_type=car_type.replace('\n', '').replace('\t','')
car_type1=car_type.split('[')[1].split(',')[0]
car_type1=car_type1.encode("utf-8")                //Conversion to utf-8 string
print(car_type1)
print(type(car_type1))
lis.append(car_type1)
print(lis)
```

Following is the output:

```
Z(76.9萬)

type 'str'

['Z(76.9\xe8\x90\xac)']
```

I am not sure why everytime when I append car_type1 in lis, there's always a unicode problem. Any way to solve it? Cause I need to write lis into csv. Thanks!

Comment: You'll have better luck with Python 3 if you can switch.  Printable Unicode will display as characters instead of escape codes in lists.  Also since you mentioned writing to .CSV files, look into the `csv` module which works with Unicode *much* better in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Its not a problem of your `car_type1` object being a `string` object or an `unicode` object.

When you print a string in python, you get the output of the `__str__` method of the object i.e. `Z(76.9萬)`.

However, the `__str__` method of a list works a bit differently. It creates a string containing the opening and closing brackets `[]` and the string produced by the `__repr__` method of each object inside the list.

Simplistically, when you print an object, it's `__str__` method gets called, and the `__str__` method of list constructs it's output by calling `__repr__` method if string objects inside it.

If you want it to work the way you want, you can do it the following way:

```
print '[' + ','.join("'" + str(l) + "'" for l in lis) + ']'
```

You can write to file easily in the following manner:

```
>>> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
>>> import io
>>>
>>> a = u'Z(76.9萬)'
>>> a
u'Z(76.9\u842c)'
>>> print a
Z(76.9萬)
>>> type(a)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> with io.open('/tmp/test', 'w') as file:
...     file.write(a)
... 
8L
>>>
```

Following is the output of the file:

```
$ cat /tmp/test
Z(76.9萬)
```

Comment: Hi! It can print out successfully, but after this, I need to write them into csv and it won't work in this case.

Comment: Really appreciate for your help! I actually need to write the whole list "lis" into csv file instead of only writing one unicode. I still tried yours, edit '/tmp/test' as 'test.csv' and 'w' as 'a', but when I opened the csv file, it shows "? ?" instead of "萬"

Comment: `w` means open file in `write` format. Don't change that to `a`